How to get comments on posts in a telegram channel?
I tried to use get_discussion_message. .id was determined correctly. but .text and .author belonged to the post itself.
ch = -...

app = Client(
    "my_account",
    api_id=...,
    api_hash="..."
)

async def main():
    await app.start()

    async for message in app.get_chat_history(ch):
        try:
            msg = await app.get_discussion_message(ch, message.id)
            print(msg)
        except:
            None
    await app.stop()


app.run(main())


Does this answer your question? How to read message that has been replied to in telegram using telethon

To retrieve comments on a post in a Telegram channel using Pyrogram, you should utilize the get_discussion_replies method instead of get_discussion_message. Here's a code snippet demonstrating how to achieve this:
import asyncio

from pyrogram import Client

CHAT_ID = ... # Your channel id here


async def main():
    async with Client("session") as client:
        async for message in client.get_chat_history(CHAT_ID):
            async for reply in client.get_discussion_replies(CHAT_ID, message.id):
                print(reply)


asyncio.run(main())

This code will fetch the comments (or replies) associated with the specified post in the given channel.
